# Streaming CSV with akka-http in scala

Tags: scala, csv, akka, akka-http

I am very new to akka-http, and I would like to stream a csv with an arbitrary number of lines.

For instance, I would like to return :

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

with the following code

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val map = new mutable.HashMap[String, Int]()
map.put("a", 1)
map.put("b", 2)
map.put("c", 3)
val `text/csv` = ContentType(MediaTypes.`text/csv`, `UTF-8`)
val route =
  path("test") {
    complete {
      HttpEntity(`text/csv`, ??? using map)
    }
  }
Http().bindAndHandle(route,"localhost",8080)
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT: Thanks to Ramon J Romero y Vigil**

```
package test


import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream._
import akka.util.ByteString

import scala.collection.mutable

object Test{

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
    implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val map = new mutable.HashMap[String, Int]()
    map.put("a", 1)
    map.put("b", 2)
    map.put("c", 3)

    val mapStream = Stream.fromIterator(() => map.toIterator)
      .map((k: String, v: Int) => s"$k,$v")
      .map(ByteString.apply)
    val `text/csv` = ContentType(MediaTypes.`text/csv`, `UTF-8`)
    val route =
      path("test") {
        complete {
          HttpEntity(`text/csv`, mapStream)
        }
      }
    Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)

  }
}
```

With this code I have two compile error:

```
Error:(29, 28) value fromIterator is not a member of object scala.collection.immutable.Stream
val mapStream = Stream.fromIterator(() => map.toIterator)

Error:(38, 11) overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (contentType: akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType,file: java.io.File,chunkSize: Int)akka.http.scaladsl.model.UniversalEntity <and>
  (contentType: akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType,data: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,Any])akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Chunked <and>
  (contentType: akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType,data: akka.util.ByteString)akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Strict <and>
  (contentType: akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType,bytes: Array[Byte])akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Strict <and>
  (contentType: akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType.NonBinary,string: String)akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Strict
 cannot be applied to (akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType.WithCharset, List[akka.util.ByteString])
          HttpEntity(`text/csv`, mapStream)
```

I used a List of tuples to get arround the first issue (hower i do not know how to stream a map in Scala)
No idea for the second
Thanks for your help.

(I am using scala 2.11.8)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `apply` function in [`HttpEntity`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.42089507.723935664.1469018756#akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity$) that takes in a `Source[ByteString,Any]`.  The apply creates a [`Chunked`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.42089507.723935664.1469018756#akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity$$Chunked) entity.  You can read your file using code based on the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-io.html#Streaming_File_IO) for streaming file IO using an akka stream [`Source`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.42089507.723935664.1469018756#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source$):

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

val file = Paths.get("yourFile.csv")

val entity = HttpEntity(`txt/csv`, FileIO.fromPath(file))
```

The stream will break up your file into chunk sizes, [default is currently set to 8192](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.42089507.723935664.1469018756#akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO$).

To stream the map that you've created you can use a similar trick:

```
val mapStream = Source.fromIterator(() => map.toIterator)
                      .map( (k : String, v : Int) => s"$k,$v" )
                      .map(ByteString.apply)

val mapEntity = HttpEntity(`test/csv`, mapStream)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how should I use this for streaming my map rather than a file ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a type mismatch compile error, expected ToResponseMarshallable, actual Any. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ogen I can't help with compiler errors without your full code and compiler output.  My answer is to your original question: "I would like to stream a csv with an arbitrary number of lines".  I answered that question...

Comment: @ogen I fixed my answer, it should be `Source.fromIterator` not `Stream.fromIterator`.

Comment: @ogen You are welcome.  You should probably change your question to reflect the compiling code.  Happy hacking.